# Oracle SQL: Select a Max of of two subsets from table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  a table that is formatted like:

```
Customer Code Date
Cust1    aa   '18-Mar-01'
Cust1    ab   '18-Apr-05'
Cust1    ac   '18-Feb-20'
Cust1    ba   '18-Mar-03'
Cust1    bb   '18-Apr-06'
Cust1    bc   '18-May-30'
Cust2    aa   '18-Jun-08'
Cust2    ab   '18-May-15'
Cust2    ac   '18-May-07'
Cust2    ba   '18-Apr-26'
Cust2    bb   '18-Jun-17'
Cust2    bc   '18-Mar-29'
```

I am trying to get this:

```
Customer Code1 Date        Code2 Date
Cust1    ab    '18-Apr-05' bc   '18-May-30'
Cust2    aa    '18-Jun-08' bb   '18-Jun-17'
```

I am trying to get max of code 'a*' and the date, and 'b*' and the date. I have been using max but I only get the date and not the corresponding code. When I use rank I haven't been able to get the second code. Any ideas?

```
Select c1.cust_num, 
       c1.cust_stat, 
       p1.cs_code, 
       p1.cs_est_comp_date, 
       p1.cs_act_comp_date 
       (select max(t.Cust_Codes.cs_act_comp_date) 
        from t.Cust_Codes 
        where t.cust_code.cs_code in ('AA','A1','A2')) as c1date, 
       (select max(t.Cust_Codes.cs_act_comp_date) 
        from t.Cust_Codes 
        where t.cust_code.cs_code in ('BA','A0','B2')) as c2date, 
from t.Cust c1, 
     t.Cust_Codes p1 
Where c1.cust_num = p1.cust_num (+) 
  and c1.cust_stat = 'O'
```

Comment: What did your actual query look like?

Comment: <code>
Select
    c1.cust_num,
    c1.cust_stat,
    p1.cs_code,
    p1.cs_est_comp_date,
    p1.cs_act_comp_date
    (select max(t.Cust_Codes.cs_act_comp_date) from t.Cust_Codes where t.cust_code.cs_code in ('AA','A1','A2')) as c1date,
(select max(t.Cust_Codes.cs_act_comp_date) from t.Cust_Codes where t.cust_code.cs_code in ('BA','A0','B2')) as c2date,
from
    t.Cust c1,
    t.Cust_Codes p1
Where
    c1.cust_num = p1.cust_num (+)
    and c1.cust_stat = 'O'
</code>

Comment: Please include that query as a code element in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI-standard window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select customer,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and code like 'a%' then code end) as code_a,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and code like 'a%' then date end) as date_a,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and code like 'b%' then code end) as code_b,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 and code like 'b%' then date end) as date_b
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by substr(code, 1, 1) order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by customer;
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try to use this I am getting a 'missing keyword' error when I try this.

Comment: @bismark03, replace `left(code, 1)` to `substr(code, 1, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a function called [`first_value`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions059.htm#SQLRF00642).

```
with
  q as(
    select Customer, substr(Code, 1, 1) Ch,
      first_value(Code) over(
        partition by Customer, substr(Code, 1, 1) order by "Date" desc) Code,
      first_value("Date") over(
        partition by Customer, substr(Code, 1, 1) order by "Date" desc) "Date"
    from t
  )
select Customer,
  max(decode(ch, 'a', Code)) Code1, to_char(max(decode(ch, 'a', "Date")), 'rr-Mon-dd') Date1,
  max(decode(ch, 'b', Code)) Code2, to_char(max(decode(ch, 'b', "Date")), 'rr-Mon-dd') Date2
from q
group by Customer;
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I can't get this to run. Also decode doesn't work as not all code that start with 'a' are part of 'start' process.